# Touch Id autotrigger success when i dismiss from another view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, touch-id

the process is : 
1 the user login with touch id 
2 the user logout (logout dismiss to login)
  then the app autotrigger touch id with success response (this not happen in the emulators) HELP!!

this is my listener on login viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)      

    if authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) && DataContainerSingleton.sharedDataContainer.fingerPrintEnabled == "SI"{
        self.touchIdListener()
    }


}
```

with

```
  func touchIdListener(){
    authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
        .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
        localizedReason: self.valFromCurrentLanguaje(valor: "LOGIN_FINGER_MSG"),
        reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in

            if( success ) {
                let keychain = KeychainSwift()
                let data = keychain.get(Constants.USER_KEY)?.components(separatedBy: ",")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showProgress(text: Constants.EMPTY_STRING)
                }
                self.fromTouchId = true
                self.loginBL.startLogin(email: (data?[0])!, password: data?[1])
            }else {
                // Check if there is an error
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

                }

            }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was change the dismiss

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for a new instance

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard()
            let vc : LoginViewController
            if (Constants.IS_IPAD) {
                storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "LoginIpad", bundle: nil)
                vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ipadViewController") as! LoginViewController
            } else {
                storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
                vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iphoneViewController") as! LoginViewController
            }
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```